# DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE()) - Does it take time into account?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, dateadd

I am writing a SQL query in Aginity through Amazon Redshift to extract the last 7 days of data. The `Date` column which I am calling is in the variable type:

`DATE`

An example output is this:

`5/30/2017 0:00`

When I call the below function, does it matter what time of day I run this query or will it always take the full day's worth of data?

`WHERE Date  >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())`

Comment: datetime functions are highly vendor specific, and the [tag:sql] tag applies to the ANSI standard. Please [edit] your question and add a specific vendor tag (if I had to guess, maybe [tag:sql-server]?)

Comment: I'm running it in Amazon Redshift in Aginity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this includes the current time component when subtracting 7 days.  To get rid of that, convert to a date:

```
WHERE Date >= CAST(DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE()) as DATE)
```

Comment: Thanks appreciate it